# Show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] = \{a + b\sqrt{2}\}$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}] = \{a + b\sqrt{2}\} $ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}.$

I understand that posting questions without showing your work is looked down upon, however, speaking freely, I don’t know how to even begin the demonstration. I know how to demonstrate something is a vector space, I don’t know how to operate with $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.

Comment: Which words and symbols do you understand? It's very hard for us to help you if we don't have any idea where you're getting stuck when you try to start.

Comment: Everything except how to deal with Q[sqrt{2}]. By the way I’m on my phone so formatting mathjax takes too long.

Comment: The operations are the usual operations in $\mathbb{R}$. You know how to add real numbers and how to multiply a real number by a rational scalar. So show that $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ is closed under these operations.

Comment: The easiest way is to identify $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ as subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ as $\mathbb{Q}$ vector space. $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ contains all numbers of the form $a+b\sqrt{2}$ with $a,b\in\mathbb{Q}$. Can you show that $0$ is of this form? Can you show that the sum of two expressions of this form has the same form again? Can you show that the product of such an expression with a rational has the same form again? If you manage to show these, you're done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might get you started:

We have a field $\mathbb{Q}$ with the usual interpretation of $\oplus$ and $\odot$.
I write $\oplus$ and $\odot$, which might look confusing, but I think it helps, because we actually want to seperate the usual $+$ and $\cdot$ you know from $(\mathbb{Q},+,\cdot)$ here. But, as it turns out, they are just the same.

Why is it still helpful? 
Because we want to know, where the structure comes from (laws of a associativity, commutativity, distributivity) and you already know, that these hold for the usual $+$ and $\cdot$.

First of all we have to show, that $\oplus:\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]\times\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]\to\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$, $(x,y)\mapsto x+y$ is 'closed' under addition. So when you add two elements from $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ then the sum is an element of $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.

> Note again, that $+$ is the sign you already know by heart.

So let $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$. By definition of this set, it is $x=a+\sqrt{2}b$ and $y=c+\sqrt{2}d$, with $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Now we have to show, that $x+y\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.
That means it has to be $x+y=a'+\sqrt{2}b'$ for some $a',b'\in\mathbb{Q}$.

And finding them is a simple task, since

$\underbrace{\oplus(x,y)}_{\text{Again, this ist just notation}}=\underbrace{(a+\sqrt{2}b)+(c+\sqrt{2}d)}_{\text{by definition of the binary operation $\oplus$}}=\underbrace{(a+c)}_{=a'}+\sqrt{2}\underbrace{(b+d)}_{=b'}$

So indeed we have $x+y\in\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$.

> Note that we use for the last equality, that $+$ and $\cdot$ (where I used the common notation of $x\cdot y=xy$) already has these properties of associativity, commutativity and distributivity.

There are a bunch of axioms to show, all are pretty much really simple, if you just try.
Let me show one more:

We have to give a neutral element, with regards to $+$, for $(\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}],\oplus,\odot)$ to be a vectorspace.

This is given by $0+0\sqrt{2}=0$

Because it is $\oplus(x,0)=(a+\sqrt{2}b)+(0+\sqrt{2}0)=(a+0)+\sqrt{2}(b+0)=a+\sqrt{2}b=x$

And $\oplus(0,x)=(0+\sqrt{2}0)+(a+\sqrt{2}b)=(0+a)+\sqrt{2}(0+b)=a+\sqrt{2}b=x$

> Note, that $0$ already has this property in the field $(\mathbb{Q}, +,\cdot)$.

The other axioms can be shown this way.
I hope this little guide helps.

Comment: It helped. I understand now that $(a + b\sqrt{2})$ is to be treated as a vector. The rest follows easily. Thanks.

Comment: Otherwise it might help, when you study how you show, that $\mathbb{C}$ is a field. Because there you write the elements as (a,b) where a is the real part and b is the imaginary part. Here you can write this as (a,b) too, as you said "treat it like a vector". Where a is the rational part and b is the $\sqrt{2}$-part. But it is simpler, since $\mathbb{C}$ has an odd multiplication, which $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{2}]$ has not.

Comment: I have shown that C is a field.

Answer (score 1):

An $F$-vectorspace is an abelian group equipped with an $F$-action i.e. it is a set $V$ with a binary operation $+$ such that $(V,+)$ is an abelian group and another operation $\cdot : F \times V \to V$ satisfying field action axioms. I am sure you've seen the definition of a vectorspace before, but I believe it is helpful to go back to basics. Does this set

$$\mathbb{Q} = \{a+b\sqrt{2} : a,b \in \mathbb{Q}\}$$

satisfy the axioms of a $\mathbb{Q}$-vectorspace? What is addition? What is scalar multiplication?